# Google Apps Script - Linear scale in google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-people-api, google-apps-script-api

Dears
I have a survey form with 13 questions, there is a condition which says: in case the user inserted all answers with the same value for examples all answers was 1 from 5 or all 5 from 5 don't submit the form and give the error to the user with a message like as " Sorry , not possible all answer be in same range ".
How can I do that please?

Comment: Use a standard html form and webapp.  I don't believe you can do it with a form.  From sound of your question you'll probably want to hire someone to assist you because first timers without prior javascript, html, css experience will find the process a bit daunting

Comment: Thanks, Cooper, Actually I am familiar with all language you mentioned but the requirement is to do the task with a google form. as much as I saw the apps script I do believe that its possible to do that just I'm looking to see how

Comment: You could be correct.  I don't use Google Forms much myself as I prefer to invest the time in vehicles that offer greater flexibility and interactivity.